# Countable and Uncountable Nouns in a List

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, lists, countable-nouns

Since "information" is an uncountable-noun and "references" is a countable noun, which sentence is correct?

- > Please let me know if any additional information or references **are** needed.
- > Please let me know if any additional information or references **is** needed.

Comment: One option would be to reword the sentence: __Please let me know if you need any additional information or references.__ Of course, this also switches from passive to active voice, which you may not want.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Ibrahim. Firstly, I don't think that coordinating a non-count and a count noun poses any problems per se; it certainly doesn't jar here. But secondly, it would seem that the rules for agreement with compound subjects should apply, and one can find these by basic research.

Comment: What @EdwinAshworth said. Short answer: we normally honour the "plurality" of ***the last item in the list***.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying. I was confused how it was a duplicate at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ibrahim, and welcome to ELU.

First of all, you are right in your distinction between nouns that have no plural (like *information*) and nouns that have a plural (like *reference*).  Strictly, nouns without a plural are called ***count*** *nouns*.  It is not the nouns that can or cannot be counted, but the things to which they refer.

Some nouns can be used as **either** count nouns or as non-count nouns:-

> *Bread* as in "Please pass  the bread".  In this sentence the only thing that can be counted is a **loaf of** bread, as in "Would you like two **loaves of** bread or one?"
>
> *Justice*, as in "All people are entitled to justice.", has no plural.

But each of these **words** has a slightly different meaning, in which it refers to something which **can** be counted.

> "Some bakers make many different breads (that is **types of**bread); others specialise in just one (type of) bread."
>
> This city's court operates with three resident **justices** (ie justices of the peace)."

Coming back to your main point, sentences like the one you cite are typical of how writers can find themselves in no-win situations.  Whichever way round you put it, the sentence will jar.  At least, it will jar on any native speaker of English paying attention to (some might say “fussy about”) what it being said.

Your second version is easier to bear because the plural verb is close to the plural noun.  But this has nothing to do with count nouns themselves or with their opposites. You can generate the same discomfort without this.

> Can you tell me whether six red roses or a single rose are/is needed?

There is a simple rule:  **avoid having more than one subject to a verb, if one is singular and the other plural.**

And there is an easy way to do this in your case, by following another simple rule, this time one of style:

> Prefer active verbs to passive ones.

So in this case, it is fair to assume that the people either in need or not in need of the information or references are those who commissioned the writer asking the question.  If so, then write:-

> Please let me know if you need any additional information or references.

Bang goes the problem.

Of course, there is another equally simple way round the problem in this case, which is to use the conjunction *and* in place of the disjunction *or*

> Let me know if any additional information **and** references **are** needed.

Comment: You need to clear up your first substantive paragraph. And note that it's better to distinguish count and non-count **usages** (arabica and robusta are the two main _coffees_ grown; _coffee_ is my favourite drink). Otherwise, a good answer (though apart from your examples, it's all been covered here before).

Comment: @Chappo It was staring me in the face, but still I couldn’t see it till today.  I am grateful to you and to Edwin for pointing out the howler!